# Create view of struct with span c++

Tags: c++, c++20

Imagine I have following struct

```
struct Base {
    float a {1};
    float b {2};
    float c {3};
    float d {4};
};
```

How can I create view of `b` and `c` of this struct via `std::span`?
For example:

```
Base base;
std::span<float, 2> sliced {(float)&base+1, (float)&base+2};
```

Comment: You can't: It's undefined behavior. You don't have any array, so pointer arithmetic is meaningless.

Comment: As a general rule, if you feel the need to do a C-style cast (the `(float)` part) then you should take that as a sign that you're doing something wrong.

Comment: And what is the *actual* problem you need to solve? Why do you need a "view" of these two members? Right now this is very much an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info). Please ask about your actual problem directly instead.

Comment: `Base` can have an array of references (`std::reference_wrapper`) to the members, but I am not really suggesting to do this. Why are the members of `Base` not elements of an array?

Comment: Can't `Base` just be replaced with `std::array<float,4>` and remove the need for a span?

Comment: Thank you guys. It XY problem indeed. But I was really interested in creating view of fields of struct. If it undefined, i will accept that.

Answer (score 0):

This is UB. One reason is that there may be padding in the struct, so those data members may not be "contiguous" in the sense of an array or span.